# Should I use MySQL's primary key as ID in Elasticsearch?

Tags: mysql, database, search, elasticsearch

I'm using an MySQL for storing data for a mobile app backend server. Now I want to add search capability and have been exploring Elasticsearch, AWS ES specifically, for the same. My question is about the datamodel used in Elasticsearch. I have the following table in MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE User
(
Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);
```

Now I want to be able to search on User.Name. My question is if it's a good idea to keep the _id in ES as same as the User.id in MySQL so that any subsequent updates can be managed in both(MySQL and ES) easily.

```
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/index/user/1' -d '{
    "name" : "Roger Federer",
    "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of ES 2.0, you're [free to use](https://www.elastic.co/blog/performance-indexing-2-0) your own IDs without performance penalty. It wasn't the case [in pre-2.0 releases](https://www.elastic.co/blog/performance-considerations-elasticsearch-indexing).

However, the type of ID you choose will have an [impact on indexing performance](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2014/05/choosing-fast-unique-identifier-uuid.html). Your MySQL primary key is a sequential integer and according to the latter link, it performs OK, so you shouldn't encounter any issues. According to that same link, if you want to increase the performance a bit more, you can use your primary key but zero-pad it in order to create the ES id, so that the MySQL record with `ID: 1` has the ES `_id: 000000001`.

Besides, as you rightly said, keeping the same ID will allow you to better manage updates and synchs between both data sources.

Answer (score 1):

This is particularly an implementation decision. So you have to decide up on it. In my use cases, I use to keep both Id's as same for sake of managing the docs. The case is that if your Id doesn't make sense in ES docs, you can even leave it unspecified, ES will manage it for you.